# Re positioning a View from Linear Layout to relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have two Layouts a linearLayout with vertical orientation and relativeLayout,
and I'm moving views from the linearLayout to the relativeLayout dynamically using getLocationOnScreen

```
                    int[] cellLocation = new int[2];
                    targetCellImage.getLocationOnScreen( cellLocation );
                    int posX = cellLocation[0];
                    int posY = cellLocation[1];
                    //change the tag for the cell (black or white)
                    targetCellImage.setTag( currentPlayer );

            //remove any previous rules related to the stone previous layout
                    layoutParams2.removeRule( 
                       RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT );
                    layoutParams2.removeRule( RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END );
                    layoutParams2.setMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
                    //reset padding and make the stone move
                    stone.setPadding( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
                    if (stone.getParent() != null) ((ViewGroup) 
                       stone.getParent()).removeView( stone );
                    mainLayout.addView( stone, layoutParams2 );

                    //set the stone tag to the Id of the current cell
                    // move the stone to that cell
                    stone.setTag( targetCellIDName );
                    stone.setX( posX);
                    stone.setY( posY);
```

this code works perfectly except for one problem I pumped into by accident, when I click the first view in the LinearLayout it goes right where it should be, but if I clicked the last view somehow the y axis is shifted and the new position is not correct.

[image: I click this view and the new position is correct]

[image: but when I click the las view it is not moving to the same prev pos]

Why is this happening...I hope my question is clear

Comment: I solved this by actually deleting the selected view and create a new one in the specific location.